# Why on SPO cannot create a folder named Con.te while on SP2016 onPrem I can?

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2016, error, modern-experience, folder

I have a problem while migrating data from SP2016 OnPrem to SPO.

In my OnPrem environment I have, for example, a folder named "Con.te" and sharegate report me an error while migrating on SPO.

If I try to create manually the folder on SPO I receive an error because folder name contains invalid characters. On the other side it's possible to create a folder with this name (Con.te) on SP2016 and users did it.

Is there any way to enable these folder names in SPO?

Answer (score 0):

I have observed the similar behavior in our SharePoint online tenant.

As per the [Restrictions and limitations in OneDrive and SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restrictions-and-limitations-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa),

> These names aren't allowed for files or folders: **.lock, CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM0 - COM9, LPT0 - LPT9, *vti*, desktop.ini**, any filename starting with **~$**.

Also, I don't think there is any way to enable these folder names in SharePoint online. You can create support ticket with Microsoft for further clarification.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. 
I had already read the documentation about not allowed names, but I was amazed that on SP2016 creation is allowed without problems.


I also believed that the name "CON" was forbidden, but not the fact of using it as a prefix (eg Con.te)

I'll try to ask Microsoft with a ticket. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome Loris. There are different limitations in SP 2016 & SP online & these cannot be changed in SP online environment. So, best way is to connect with Microsoft.

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if my reply helped you in any way.